# svn co-ci taking different default user

Tags: svn

I had setup a svn server locally, and then tried to setup a username/password system, but that somehow didn't work. I left that as it is, as the basic co and ci was working well, and the repo was consistent.

But after doing about 20 commit operations, when I had a look at `svn log`, it shows all the updates done by some other username('test' in this case). I tired to checkout a fresh copy without giving any username, and checked in again. To my surprise it was again the same username 'test'.

Output of `svn log`

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r20 | test | 2012-07-29 22:58:03 +0530 (Sun, 29 Jul 2012) | 1 line

Added useful svn commands.
```

So, from where does the svn pick this default user? I want the commits to be logged in by my username i.e. the login name 'mtk', and not by the other username 'test'.

Any pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the standard default command line client, the authentication is stored under the `$HOME/.subversion/auth` directory. In your case, probably under the `$HOME/.subversion/auth/svn.simple` directory.

If the Subversion client finds an authentication record that matches a URL, it uses that user and password as the default. This way, you don't have to keep logging in every time you do something in Subversion. By the way, the *credentials* are cached by default, but you can change that via the `$HOME/.subversion/config` file.

If you're using `svnserve` as your Subversion server, your problem is probably not setting up the `svnserve.conf` file correctly. It's a common issue many beginners have. Go to the repository directory and edit the `svnserve.conf` file which is in the `conf` directory.

Around line #27 is the line `# password-db = passwd`. Remove that leading `#` and space. Then, you need to edit the `passwd` file with the user credentials you want. There's a template `passwd` file there already. Most beginners edit the `passwd` file, but forget to remove the leading `#` in the `.svnserve.conf` file that specifies which password credential file to use.

Comment: > I am not using svnserve. > There is a directory `svn.simple`. Please let me know, how to change the default checkout-checking-in user. There are no user entries in the files mentioned by you. Thanks

Comment: What are you using as a server? Are you using `file://`? If you're using `file://` switch to `svnserve`. It's easy [enough to setup](http://subversion.open.collab.net/articles/svnserve-service.htm) and is more flexible. I never use `file://` even for private repos. Or, are you using `http://` via Apache httpd? If so, it's Apache handling all the configuration and users. See the [online manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html) for configuring Apache.

Comment: Very helpful link of apache. Let me go through it, huge doc :)